# Equivalent to the numpy where function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is my problem, I have two columns as below :

```
 A   B
-3   4
-6  -8
12  14
```

I would like to create a code that replace all the values by 1 if the value is > -2 and by 0 if not.

I know that with numpy it would have been simple by using 
`d["newcolum"]=np.where(d < -2,1,0)` but I have more difficulties with pandas as its where function just show the value if the condition is not met.

Do you guys know something that could help me? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain reason why cannot use this function in pandas?

Comment: Sure, it is because with numpy I have the error : ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want set `0` and `1` values convert boolean mask to integer:

```
df = (df < -2).astype(int)
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  0  0
```

Using `np.where` ia absolutely fine, only need DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df < -2,1,0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's exactly what I was looking for. I forgot to use the DataFrame constructor. It's perfect now thank you